# linking error with CMake and Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to compile [osgearth](http://osgearth.org) library with VS2010. The library uses CMake, so after setting all dependencies it generates a VS2010 solution file. However when running build in VS I get this linker error (and 200 similar ones)

Error   7   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __thiscall std::basic_ofstream >::`vbase destructor'(void)" (_*imp*??_D?$basic_ofstream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAEXXZ) referenced in function "public: virtual void __thiscall osgEarth::DiskCache::setImage(class osgEarth::TileKey const &,struct osgEarth::CacheSpec const &,class osg::Image const *)" (?setImage@DiskCache@osgEarth@@UAEXABVTileKey@2@ABUCacheSpec@2@PBVImage@osg@@@Z)  C:\swproj\osgearth-src\src\osgEarth\Caching.obj osgEarth

I'm not very familiar with C++, is there anything else I have to set up?

Comment: that was eight years ago, sorry :)

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a reference to std::ofstream.  You either need an #include  in one of your files or a reference to the standard library dll in your project.